# Is there any way to detect that indexed db is blocked due readwrite or versionchange in multiple tab

Tags: indexeddb

Is there any way to detect that indexed db is blocked due readwrite or versionchange locks in multiple tab.how to detect the lock is released and then continue with readwrite or versionchange operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect that an indexedDB database is blocked in another tab, you can listen for the blocked event when connecting to the database.

```
const request = indexedDB.open(...);
request.onblocked = function(event) {
  console.log('blocked :(');
};
```

As Mr. Bell states in the comments, a block event does not mean a success event will never fire, it just means the connection process is 'paused' while blocked (indefinitely). Simply listening for the success event indicates the connection process is no longer blocked.

```
const wasBlocked = false;
const request = indexedDB.open(...);
request.onblocked = function(event) {
  wasBlocked = true;
};
request.onsuccess = function(event) {
  if(wasBlocked) {
    fireUnblockedEvent(...);
  }
};
```

Comment: A blocked open (or delete) is not canceled, just... blocked. Once unblocked the open (or delete) will proceed.

Comment: Also note that an open will only be blocked if it's attempting to upgrade the database version (i.e. a version number is passed that is higher than the current version) when the other connections don't close promptly. An open with no version or the same version that's waiting on an in-progress upgrade will just wait with no event.

Comment: @JoshuaBell I did not know that blocked will eventually proceed. That is interesting. Thanks!