# Indexed db open not trigger any callback

Tags: indexeddb

We are facing a problem.
When we trying to open indexed db none of the callback is triggered.
We are doing the following steps:
1.open the database with using following steps:

```
request = indexedDB.open(name, 10);
request.onerror = onError;
request.onsuccess = onSuccess;
request.onupgradeneeded = onUpgradeNeeded;
request.onblocked=onBlocked;<br>
```

2.notice that none of the callback is triggered.
3.open chrome://indexeddb-internals/# and it shows previous delete db is pending.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably have another tab open that has a connection to the database.

Open/delete requests go into a queue. An open request that doesn't specify a version (or that specifies the same version as the current database) can be processed immediately when it gets to the front of the queue. An open request for a higher version or a delete request that gets to the front of the queue must wait for all other connections to close. If they close immediately upon receiving "versionchange" then the request proceeds. If not the request gets a "blocked" event and waits until the connections close.

Note that other requests in the queue don't get events - they're just waiting until they get to the front of the queue and either get processed or "blocked"

In step 3 you report that there's a previous delete request pending. That indicate it's blocked on something; presumably there's another connection hanging around. So the delete request is at the front of the queue and "blocked", and your open request (for version 10) is sitting behind it in the queue, and (as you note) it won't see events until it makes it to the front of the queue.

Comment: Is there any way to clear indexed db without deleting to avoid such activities?

Comment: During upgrade you can enumerate and delete all of the object stores. (But of course an upgrade would be blocked by open connections as well.)

Comment: I'd suggest looking at other answers for guidance on how to have connections observe the "versionchange" event and react appropriately, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40032008/how-should-an-app-react-when-indexeddb-is-blocked

Answer (score 2):

Although the answer of Joshua Bell is correct I would like to add (based on his answer :) that blocked = upgradeBlocked (which happens only if you have a keep-connection-open policy and your app is open in more than 1 tab and you try to upgrade your schema in a tab but other open connection in another tab does not close on versionchange event which fires there as well... so upgrade is blocked) and your code seems to be queueBlocked but you do not have a listener to that.

I myself implemented a timeout for requests so that I always know that either timeout, success, upgrade&success or error fires in the time frame timeout provides. I assume blocked never happens since I always close connections on versionchange.

But of course good code normally does not face a timeout I guess. So this is for immaculate  runtime handling. If you frequently encounter timeout, the source of the problem is somewhere else. So having onBlockedUpgrade and onBlockedQueue would not really help. Having built in timeout like by xhr would be great :)

But great to know this "queue thing" from Joshua Bell :) You had better implement timeout and in this concrete case you should find the problem elsewhere.